# Is there any reason or advantage of using both session cookies and redis store for sessions

Tags: session, flask, redis

Context

In a flask app, we use a signed cookie (encoded JWT) for user data, however the amount of data has become too large to put in a cookie (specific permissions per item).

Here comes redis, instead of storing the permissions in the JWT and passing it back and forth, we'll just keep it in redis.

My questions are

1. Is there any advantage to having signed session cookies (encoded JWT) AND using redis to store other session information
2. Is it better to implement the session logic yourself instead of using something like [flask-session](https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even you use `Redis` to store sessions you still need cookies since you will need to query by key and the key will be one the client side, in the cookie.

You may just keep the identifier in the cookie but store the rest in redis and you get the details by that identifier.

1. I think it would be secure to have some long, hard-to-know identifier as key instead of just some integer, or some arbitrary short text.
2. I am not super familiar with `flask` but, the requirements for the `session` is almost same for the years(get, set, expire, delete) and probably that library supports all the requirements for session related use cases. I would go with the existing one instead of implementing new.

Comment: yeah I ended up coming to the same conclusion, "I think it would be secure to have some long, hard-to-know identifier as key instead of just some integer" I was considering just using the user_id, what would you advise in place of this ? an encoded id ?

Comment: Yes some long and arbitrary number(salted with userid etc), otherwise someone may edit his cookie and make a request to fetch some other people's number. @steff_bdh

Comment: I use application signatures to prevent modifications from the user side, so other than mods is there any other reason to obscure ?

Comment: @steff_bdh i think no, the only thing is security reasons but if you covered that area, i don't think any reason.

Comment: @steff_bdh how are you using `application signatures` to prevent modifications? mind sharing your solution to this? thanks

Comment: So generally signatures work by combining the 'public' data with a private / secret key to generate some value (signature) to be passed along with that public data; when that data is sent back the server it attempts to recreate the signature (secret key + passed data) if the signature that was passed back does not match the signature the server generates then the server knows it was modified; and no one else can generate the correct signature since the key is kept secret to the server; Here's link on how to do it in flask https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#configuration-basics

Answer (score 1):

JWT is mostly useful for distibuted applications where the token is generated and used by different applications. So, if all processing happens on a single backend, redis is more flexible.
Implementing your own session logic is probably not a good idea, especially when the session is used for security purposes (authentication).

Comment: nothing bad in creating one's own session logic for custom security...default security used by everyone because it is convenient is not great security...and sure you have to know what you doing